# Interfacing GSM module with nodemcu

Tags: lua, gsm, esp8266

I wrote this code to interface the gsm module, can anyone check the code and give me some propositions ?

```
hex1= '0x1A';
function delay_s(delay)
delay = delay or 1
local time_to = os.time() + delay
while os.time() < time_to do end
end
uart.alt(1);
uart.setup(0, 9600, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, 1)
uart.write(0,"AT+IPR=9600\n")
for j = 1, 10 do
uart.write(0, "AT\n")
end
delay_s(1000)
uart.write(0, "AT\n")
delay_s(1000)
uart.write(0, 'AT+CSCS="GSM"\n')
delay_s(1000)
uart.write(0, 'AT+CMGF=1\n')
delay_s(1000)
uart.write(0, 'AT+CMGS="+21654102832"\n')
delay_s(1000)
uart.write(0, " Salut tout le mond !!!\n")
delay_s(1000)
uart.write(0, hex1)
delay_s(1000)
```

Comment: Please provide the module model

Comment: i have the sim900a gsm module http://www.electrodragon.com/product/sim900a-mini-dev-board/

Comment: Do you have anu responses from module ? Like OK. Please tey to be more specific

Comment: No, using nodemcu i don't have any responses, but i test this module with arduino and it worked perfectly.

Comment: when i change the uart.alt(1), the program that i wrote couldn't be uploaded to the  board , hav you any idea please ?

Comment: can i call to c functions (from a c library) in lua ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't fit here. Note that Stack Overflow is a question & answer site. "give me some propositions" is not a question that can have a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code won't even run on NodeMCU because the standard Lua [`os.time()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.time) will fail since the `os` module is not available. I suggest you dig into http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/lua-developer-faq/#how-is-nodemcu-lua-different-to-standard-lua.

Besides, even if it were available `os.time()` has 1 second resolution.

> The returned value is a number, whose meaning depends on your system. In POSIX, Windows, and some other systems, this number counts the number of seconds since some given start time (the "epoch").

Hence, your `delay_s(1000)` would delay execution for 1000 *seconds*. Doing that with busy-waiting is...not optimal.

You probably want to use the [`tmr` module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/tmr/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to interface the gsm module using the nodemcu, but that doesen't work. should i add software uarts iin order to be able to use other NOdemcu GPIOs ?

Answer (score 0):

```
uart.alt(x);

0 - standard pins
1 - alternate the pins
```

You havent specify which pins you are gonna use for the communication, or else use `uart.alt(0);`  for standard pins